# Mods deleting comments because they don't agree

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

I posted a comment. It was deleted. I feel that the moderator has abused their privilege to delete comments. People clearly agreed with the comment that I posted. It wasn't rude.

I simply stated that we shouldn't have to leave the website to answer someones question. The OP was demanding that we watch a video before trying to answer his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306923/c-function-that-is-not-being-called-has-to-be-present-or-code-explodes). With the question's vast edit history. It basically evolved into a new one. Here is the *original* [question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27306923/5) to which I responded with:

> Watch a video? No thanks.

I've noticed this pattern increasing rapidly over the years. Why do they even have the power to delete comments, if they are just going to delete comments that they don't agree on?

This path seems to be a **slippery slope**. If they can delete *comments*, then how long will it be before they start deleting questions?

The bottom line is moderators are deleting comments that do not need to be deleted. I believe this has high potential for abuse and should be monitored regularly.

Comment: _simply_ being the key word here. Do you want to post the comment verbatim? Careful, it might get deleted.

Comment: Seems like it became obsolete with the edits to the question.

Comment: Yes, but should we have to leave the website to answer someones question? There could have been anything on the other end, like malware.

Comment: The comment does come off as rude, in my opinion. I don't think insulting the mods will change things.

Comment: Also, it seems to me like you're saying that the mod deleted your comment because they didn't agree with it. That is, they didn't agree that we _shouldn't_ have to watch a video to answer a question, ie. they think we should follow the link and watch the video. I doubt this.

Comment: How do you determine that it "shouldn't be deleted"? Is that your personal opinion? Or have you checked this against the guidelines for deleting of comments? Are you aware what those guidelines are? Are you aware why comments are being deleted at all?

Comment: As has been stated, your comment could have been phrased more constructively and also became obsolete when information was added to the question. For those reasons, a moderator deleted it. If you don’t want to believe that, well… nobody can help you there.

Comment: The bottom line is that moderators have high potential for abuse of their power and I was a victim of such abuse tonight when my comment got deleted.

Comment: You were a victim of having an unhelpful comment that no longer applied deleted?

Comment: Yes, moderators wield power and power can be abused. No, you have not shown any concrete evidence of **abuse**. You have shown that a moderator has used the power that was given to them to remove a comment (or comments, who knows) that has been made largely obsolete and wasn't particularly insightful or constructive to begin with. I have yet to see a moderator actively removing actual pearls of wisdom *because they don't agree*. I see moderators remove largely useless comments all the time and that's exactly what they're here for. Yes, I have called your comment "largely useless".

Comment: Have you ever flagged a comment? Then you may understand why your comment was deleted. Next, why did you assume it was flagged as rude?

Comment: We can, and do, delete answers too. And accounts (under certain circumstances). We can pretty much delete anything.

Comment: friend don't worry, they just delete things which really need to be deleted, not just rude comments but also obsolete, anyway you're taking it too way personal, whoever deleted your comment didn't mean to insult you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Comments are deleted all the time, as are questions. Comments are seen as ephemeral on Stack Exchange. They are not the main content. The only purpose of comments is to provide feedback to a question or answer with the goal of improving it. Once this improvement has happened, the value of the comment is nil and it can be removed.

SE strives to remove noise. SE is not a forum. SE is an accumulation, a knowledge base, of questions and answers. This knowledge base is constantly being pruned and edited and refined and maintained to be usable to find solutions to problems. Things are removed all the time in order to keep the signal to noise ratio high.

If you feel personally harmed when one of your contributions is modified or removed in any way, SE is not the system for you.

Comment: [What are comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) _Comments are **temporary** "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer._

Answer (score 21):

You've not presented any evidence that a mod deleted your comment "because they don't agree". You report your comment as being:

> Watch a video? No thanks.

Calling the OP about the video appears to have been correct in this instance, but there are more constructive ways to do it. You could point out to the OP in so many words that links to outside resource cannot be put in the question *in place of* the information that is essential to the issue in the question.

So your comment was borderline unconstructive to start with. Then the OP edited the question in such a way that makes your comment appears obsolete. If you think there is still a problem you could put in a new and more detailed comment.

Mods regularly delete comments that are unconstructive or obsolete. This is not an abuse of the system.

> If they can delete comments, then how long will it be before they start deleting questions?

They already do delete questions, sometimes. This is a good thing. Some questions do not belong on SO.

Comment: I think the big idea here is that mods _do_ in fact abuse their "power". and it something that should be watched out for.

Comment: It is a bit silly to assert that the mods are abusing their power for doing what mods are supposed to do.

Comment: The police have guns. Does that mean they need to go around killing people they believe to be breaking the law?

Comment: @self You keep *asserting* it but you have not presented any evidence that it is the case. (And the police comparison is inapposite.)

Comment: @self No, should the community forfeit the ability to moderate the site just because a comment of yours was deleted?

Comment: How would I present evidence? A comment of mine was deleted. It wasn't rude. I don't believe the "obsolete" narrative.

Comment: @self If you take as axiomatic that you are being a victim then there is nothing anyone can say that will dissuade you, disconfirming evidence will be interpreted away, and thee is no discussion to be had.

Comment: @self one important point/question is if mods see the question in the context when they see the flag on the comment.  Standing alone, the comment may seem rude.  In the context of a big fat **Please watch the video before posting** ([context](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27306923/5)) it may be perfectly in line with the post itself.

Comment: @Michael To be fair, your comment only negates the claim that the moderators disagree with the comment. They can't disagree with something out of context. So they deleted the comment because it was rude, period.

Comment: Rude is subjective.

Comment: @remyabel moderators handle flags.  The question is how much information do they have when they handle the flag about the state of the question and related comments.  While I understand that they may be handling flags as fast as they can, there are instances where they have deleted comments about SQL injection and the like on questions as "not constructive" because the OP didn't want to deal with the security implications of the bad code (or have it brought to their attention). If the mod only sees "Watch a video? No thanks." that may be construed as rude without the full context.

Answer (score 1):

Its been mentioned before, comments are meant to be used as a type of notes/small questions towards the posters (Q or A) to ask them to clarify and(or) improve upon their post.

Once this is done, e.g. the post is improved the comment is then redundant as it is referring to something that no longer exists.

Comments will be removed to reduce any redundant information surrounding questions and answers that would take away any value from them, especially if the post is viewed retrospectively by someone also seeking that question it could add confusion.

Comment: The problem this is once someone responds to a comment, and that comment gets deleted, you are left with a hanging conversation thread: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532015/how-to-use-random-on-a-single-bit-input-register-in-verilog-testbench

Comment: If they are responding to a comment and the clarification the original comment requested has been complete I would feel they are both in need of deletion. As for the example you posted, it would seem the reply is to a potential solution provided in the form of a comment, when it should have been an answer.