# Should I clean my comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

To start with let's quote the [Comment section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) of the help center:

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

And this [useful answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278517/2307070) (emphasis is mine):

> Comments are deleted all the time, as are questions. Comments are seen as ephemeral on Stack Exchange. They are not the main content. The only purpose of comments is to provide feedback to a question or answer with the goal of improving it. Once this improvement has happened, **the value of the comment is nil and it can be removed.**

Then I did a bit of [maths on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/417755) which leads me to a bit less than 100 *useless<sup>1</sup>* comments.

I know that it's *a drop of water in an endless sea* but should I delete them and, more globally should users clean this kind of content or will the ratio time spent/gain will be too low?

---

<sup>1) I consider useless if it contains *edit* or *thanks*.</sup>

Comment: Nobody is going to stop you, how you spend your free time is up to you.

Comment: It's not against policy if that's what you're asking.  It's just probably a bit unnecessary.

Comment: Yes​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I wish I had time to clean up my comments network wide. Right now, they're mostly just a random track of dated feedback that should've been deleted. **Feature request**: post comment and delete in X minutes.

Comment: Hmm...however I think you could [get a hat from it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats) (The **Cleanup Crew**).

Comment: If you won't clean your own garbage, who else will?

Comment: IMO: comment management is entirely to be done according to what makes you feel you're doing the right thing. Don't even try to do it for the benefit of others because then there is no chance you'll ever be able to do it well enough.

Comment: I tend to delete my comments if they have no more value. For example, if I ask someone to provide an MCVE and then they edit their question to include one, well my comment is no longer useful so I'll remove it if I'm still around. It just helps reduce noise. That said, if I made a hit and run comment (perhaps I made a comment just before heading out the door) I'm not going to spend the time to go back hunting for my obsolete comments to clean up.

Comment: Amusing how @HansPassant's good, first comment about spending free time seems to have set the tone for other contributions which might otherwise have been more about site norms and less about optimal time allocation.   Deleting comments makes things smaller (good), but can sometimes remove context from surrounding content that's worth keeping (not so good).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is for nobody to dictate how *your* time is best spent than *you*.

If you feel that you do not mind spending three minutes of your day cleaning up old, obsolete comments, **by all means go ahead**. The site indeed would be [marginally] better off with obsolete comments removed, and it really doesn't take an offensive amount of time to make it so.

Personally, I try to ammortise what "cost" may be imagined, by cleaning up as I go — when a discussion about editing a post has come to a conclusion, all those comments may be removed as a last step in entertaining said discussion.

Answer (score 13):

No - there are much better ways to use your time on the site than removing comments.

Don't make comments that must be removed -- like unrelated jokes, thank you.

In case you happen to go to the question where you've commented, indeed spend an extra couple of seconds on deleting your obsolete comments (and maybe flag all other ones if there is nothing of value), but going out of your way to cleanup old comments is way less valuable than, for example, adding a new comment to a recent post or reviewing.

In rare cases, a question gets enough traffic that someone eventually flags all "fix this/missed that" comments for deletion (preferably with "other:delete all comments here"). For all other questions there is really no value to re-visit those questions and remove your comments.

Comment: _"Don't make comments that must be removed"_ Obviously, but this is about comments that were useful and now aren't. There _is_ value in keeping the noise level down by removing them. Besides, it's not for you to decide how the OP spends her or his time.

Comment: Comments that _must_ be removed? No. But I do often post transient things like "I would suggest you need to include X in this question/answer" which is irrelevant the moment the author sees it (whether they follow my advice or not).

Comment: Emphasis on not *going out of your way*, useless comments are only a real problem when the question goes on to receive high viewership and the clutter comments crowd out more valuable ones.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I read the question as  "I have some time to spent on SO: cleanup comments or something else?" and answered accordingly. Indeed OP is free to spent they time any way they pleased (as you recommended in your excellent answer), but if there is a choice how to spend time in the way most useful for community then cleaning up comments is very low on my list of things to do.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: But that's not what the question says.