# Mark comments as hidden instead of completely deleting them

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-comments

The purpose of comments on a question it to gather further information from the user asking the question. @deceze writes in [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278514/mods-deleting-comments-because-they-dont-agree) that the:

> purpose of comments is to provide feedback to a question or answer with the goal of improving it. Once this improvement has happened, the value of the comment is nil and it can be removed.

I agree on the purpose of comments, but I don't agree that they should be removed or that their value is now *nil*.

Comments can serve as a *paper-trail* for other users having the same problem as the original question poster, as different users ask for further explanation into the original question, try to confirm certain aspects of the problem, etc. Removing comments may stop new users from fully understanding the complete solution.

I suggest that instead of completely deleting comments, that admins, mods, and users can only choose to *hide* the comments. This way other user who want to see what was previous said can do so.

However, I'm not sure what to do about comments that ignore community guidelines and rules. It's possible that simply hiding these type of comments might not be enough to stop spammers, etc.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

While nothing is truly hard-deleted around here - even comments are still visible to moderators - the idea of keeping them around for non-moderators isn't practical.  If they're removed, then the context that they've served has evaporated, or they're no longer necessary.

Being someone who has the ability to see deleted answers, I won't deny that it can make a post with a sizable amount of them hard to follow.  I don't want to imagine a nightmarescape in which I have to wade through dozens of deleted comments.

Oh, did I mention that comments are also *full* of [offensive and otherwise unpleasant content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326494/1079354)?  There's no reason to expose anyone that doesn't need to be exposed to that.

Comment: Related [FR on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182091/could-30k-users-be-allowed-to-see-deleted-comments-please) and [Brad's Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182094)

Comment: I don't think that OP meant to hide every comment instead of deleting them. He most likely ment to hide former useful comment which became obsolete after a discussion/edit of the post and still burn useless comments.

Comment: @Tom:  My sentiment is the same as Don't Panic's then; if it was useful then it would be captured in something less temporal, like a question or answer.  Other than that, then it *couldn't* have been valuable enough to keep around.

Comment: @Tom is correct, that is what I meant. Sorry if that wasn't explained in the question very well. But this is now a perfect scenario to describe what I'm talking about. Tom's comment explains my question a bit further and should be added onto the end of the question itself, but also should not be completely deleted from the comments section.

Comment: @Makoto No worries, I agree on that. If a new users needs comment to understand a question, then it looks a bit like the question contains too localized information. This should be removed to create a more general question.

Comment: @mohnjatthews If my comment explains your question a bit better, then it shouldn't be appended to the end of the question, instead you should update your question to explain that equaly good as my comment did (if it actually did it that well ^^). The same applies to the comments you refer in your question: they shouldn't be needed anymore. If the question can only be understood if one reads these comments, then the question should be edited to improve that. The current version of a question should be enough to understand it.

Comment: Note that in most cases only OP of the question should be editing in such significant clarifications - editing in "I think author meant XXXXXX" into question is not an appropriate edit.

Comment: @Makoto: "*if it was useful then it would be captured in something less temporal, like a question or answer.*" And yet, I very frequently see comments that are useful which are never "captured in something less temporal". So while this may be some kind of ideal, it certainly is not frequently practiced.

Comment: "full of offensive and otherwise unpleasant content" yeah, like "Your welcome!" :D

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like what you're specifically asking about is comments that have been flagged as "obsolete", as most other reasons a comment would be deleted mean that it never had any value to begin with. Theoretically, in order for a comment to become obsolete, any useful information it contained (or requested) would have been edited into the post. In that case, I think its value *is* nil. Maybe we disagree here, but it seems like having the same information in a comment as well as in the actual post is not useful.

But comment flags are reviewed by moderators, so in theory if there was still something of value in the comment, then the obsolete flag would be declined and the comment would not be deleted.

Comment: A concern that is raised by a lot of new users to SO is that mods and admins seem to control everything with an iron fist, often removing comments without a notice as to why. Similar to how users can view exactly what a mod edited in a post, wouldn't be useful to have the ability to see what a mod deleted from the comments section. I feel it would improve the transparency of mod and admin management in SO.

Comment: I think many new users who have that concern perceive moderation that way because they feel like they've been negatively affected by it. But based on their meta questions and comments, it seems like they usually have that perception because they don't understand yet how the site is supposed to work, or what type of content is considered useful here. (And not to go off on a tangent, but anyone can edit posts, not just mods.)

Comment: @mohnjatthews - I understand the transparency arguments (which is why SO has openly visible edit histories for all posts, and even exposes deleted posts to established users), but I've found that in most cases the community is better off not seeing deleted comments. I talk about this in [the answer Jon links above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182094), but comments are the most common place for people to start fights. Deleting these comments can stop these fights before they escalate and prevent them from coming back. Leaving deleted comments visible would remove these benefits.

Comment: @BradLarson you make an excellent point! I hadn't considered that users would continue the _flame war_ in hidden comments, even when the parent comment that caused the dispute itself is hidden. Looks like there isn't any other way to fight this than to completely remove them.